# Unsubscribe another class from an event with Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, xamarin.forms

I'm working with a 3rd party library that is very tightly closed but doesn't do what I need it to (Xamarin.Forms, pan/zoom gestures).

I hacked up a work-around but with their latest update (1.4) the work-around stopped working. Looking at their code I can fix my work-around if I can unsubscribe one of the library's classes from listening to an event, the problem is that class has several private methods involved where they should have been protected.

Here's my code:

```
    public class InteractiveEventTracker: EventTracker{
        public InteractiveEventTracker(IVisualElementRenderer renderer)
            : base(renderer)
        {
            this.Renderer = renderer; 
            var elChgMethod = typeof(EventTracker).GetMethod("OnElementChanged", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var elChgDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>), elChgMethod);
// Compile-time errors, how do I spell that?
            renderer.ElementChanged -= new EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>(elChgDelegate); 
        }
```

The compile-time error is
   **Expression denotes a 'variable' where a 'type' or 'method group' was expected.**

My InteractiveEventTracker *has to* call the base constructor which looks like this:

```
public EventTracker(IVisualElementRenderer renderer)
    {
        if (renderer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("renderer");
        }
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.renderer.ElementChanged += new EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>(this.OnElementChanged); // this is what I want to unsubscribe
    }
    private void OnElementChanged(object sender, VisualElementChangedEventArgs e){
...
    }
```

How do I unsubscribe the base class, EventTracker, from listening to the event?

Comment: so why not `this.renderer.ElementChanged -= new EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>(this.OnElementChanged);`? you can change `private` to `protected` and try it

Comment: It's a 3rd-party library, I can't change EventTracker itself

Comment: on what line error? when you do unsubscribe? or create delegate?

Comment: compile-time error on the line where I try to unsubscribe

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code:

1) wrong creating delegate

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>), elChgMethod);
```

this overload method

> Creates a delegate of the specified type to represent the specified static method.

so you need pass also instance, like

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>), this, elChgMethod);
```

2) you need explicitly cast created delegate to you EventHandler type, like

```
renderer.ElementChanged -= (EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>)elChgDelegate;
```

So you need change you code like this

```
var elChgMethod = typeof(EventTracker).GetMethod("OnElementChanged", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var elChgDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>), this, elChgMethod);
renderer.ElementChanged -= (EventHandler<VisualElementChangedEventArgs>)elChgDelegate;
```